# Do we apply force to an object we are touching?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass

Since every object that has a mass induces gravity, do we actually apply some very very small force on an object (for instance a feather) when we put our hands close to it, eventually touching it, a force to attract it towards us (since we are bigger)?

Comment: (gravitational) mass attracts mass, i.e., [Cavendish experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment).  I'm not sure I grok the touching aspect of your question.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're bigger than the feather. By Newton's 3rd law, the feather's gravitational force on you is equal in strength to your gravitational force on it.

Comment: @BenCrowell Newton's 3rd law says only that every action has equal in size and opposite in direction counteraction, not that two forces generated by two objects will be equal in strength?

Comment: Not to mention gravity might not even be force but particles

Comment: You don't even have to touch an object for there to be a gravitational force on that object.

Comment: Edenia, read your statement of the Newtons law again. Since every action has the same but opposite reaction it by NECESITY means that the forces on both objects will be the same in strength, but in opposite dirrections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you apply a force on a feather when you go near it. In turn, feather applies equal force, but opposite, on you. This is not true because of Newton's 3rd law but by the construction of gravity theory by Newton. He could have defined gravitational force as follows, $$F=\frac{GM^2}{r^2},$$
but soon realize that nature does not follow this law. The fact that $$F=\frac{GMm}{r^2},$$ has dire consequences. It implies that acceleration of a body in gravity is independent of its mass. It's not a trivial statement. In fact, this fact was one of the inspiring thought for Einstein towards General Relativity. As for the direction, if one body is attracting 2nd body, the 2nd body also has to attract 1st body by symmetry.

Now one would naively believe that feather will come towards you instead you accelerating towards feather. This is true, but not because we are exerting bigger force. We simply have more inertia against the motion as compared to feather. The acceleration of feather is $F/m_{feather}$. Since mass of feather is much less than our mass, it will accelerate much faster than us.

However, in real life that's not the case. The reason is that even though the mass of the feather is really low, the force acting on it is not sufficiently high. The gravitational force on feather as to counter friction, air resistance, gravity by earth, and many other forces. Gravity of our hand is not sufficient to go against these forces.

Answer (score 0):

well, every body is experiencing force whether it is gravitational or other type of force. When we touch a body, the body may or may not move so we can eliminate work done but we cannot eliminate force, because the force might be very weak and may not change the shape/size of the object/body but the body experiences the force.

Comment: It probably experiences some kinetic energy, but what about gravity?

Comment: gravity is experienced by every body which is placed in gravitational field. Gravity is one of the weakest force, you may not experience it but it does exists, for every body that has mass.

Comment: It doesn't experience some kinetic energy. It recieves the energy and converts it into kinetic energy if it starts moving relative to it's own reference frame. If you keep the particle steady, it wouldn't "experience" any change in kinetic energy. Edenia, I just want to clear up some confusions you're having because whatever you say is half wrong. But I believe with time you can find your answers and create a more accurate model of the world in your head.